# How do I add a list header and trailer to a linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```c
   STUDENT *create_empty_list()
   {

    STUDENT *p_new_list;

        if((p_new_list = (STUDENT*) malloc(sizeof(STUDENT))) == NULL)
        { 
            printf("\nError #%d in create_empty_list.", HEADER_ALLOC_ERROR);
            exit(HEADER_ALLOC_ERROR);       
        }
        p_new_list->id_number = LIST_HEADER;

        if((p_new_list->p_next_student = (STUDENT*) malloc(sizeof(STUDENT))) == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nError #%d in create_empty_list.", TRAILER_ALLOC_ERROR);
            exit(TRAILER_ALLOC_ERROR);  
        }
        p_new_list->p_next_student->p_next_student = LIST_TRAILER;
        p_new_list->p_next_student->p_next_student = NULL;

        return p_new_list;
    }
```

I am not sure how to correctly attach the head and tail to the node.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "header" and "trailer"?

Comment: I think you mean head and tail. Header is something else in c, and tailer is nothing.

Comment: My guess is you mean something like [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) The use of a wrapper struct containing the `head` and `tail` node eliminates iterating to find the last node for an insertion preserving the input order.